# Is it better to build a spaceship in total or in parts for orbital assembly?

Tags: technology, orbital-assembly

Supposing a planned long-term manned-flight with a spaceship that has to be fairly large to accommodate many people and meet some requirements like decent shielding from radiation.

Is it better to build a large space ship in total and launch it from Earth, considering places of production, technology available, resources for logistics and costs of fuel, or is it better to construct modules/parts, which are brought to and assembled in space, also considering places of production, technology available (especially for the later assembly), resources for logistics and costs for fuel?

Comment: Am I supposed to delete the question? It is indeed a duplicate.

Comment: It's up to you, but in general, duplicates are okay.